Pyspark date parser raises timeParserPolicy upgrade exception even when already in CORRECTED mode
Spark version: 3.3.1
Python version: 3.9
By default, calling pyspark.sql.functions.to_date(col("foobar"), "yyyy-MM-dd") raises spark upgrade exception if foobar col can't be parsed using given format and, at the same time, this foobar col can be parsed with given format using legacy date parser.
Exception looks like this:
org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: 
You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: 
Fail to parse '21/09/20' in the new parser.

You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to
LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, 
or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string.

Exception is pretty descriptive but the problem is that my spark session is already configured to use CORRECTED mode.
spark.conf.get("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy") # returns CORRECTED
My Reason for using CORRECTED mode is to keep strict date checking but without raising any exceptions - if to_date(...) returns a null value then I know that this row has a date column with different format than the format that was expected which I can gracefully handle.
I tried replicating this for a very simple example but I couldn't - didn't raise any upgrade exceptions in CORRECTED mode.
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("foo") \
    .getOrCreate()


dates_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[
        (1, "2024-01-01"),
        (1, "2024-1-01"),
        (1, "2024-01-1"),
        (1, "2024-1-1"),
        (1, "24-01-01"),
        (1, "24-1-01"),
        (1, "24-01-1"),
        (1, "24-1-1"),
        (1, "2024/01/01"),
        (1, "2024/1/01"),
        (1, "2024/01/1"),
        (1, "2024/1/1"),
        (1, "24/01/01"),
        (1, "24/1/01"),
        (1, "24/01/1"),
        (1, "24/1/1"),
        (1, "11/01/2024"),
        (1, "11/1/2024"),
        (1, "11/01/24"),
        (1, "11/1/2024"),
    ],
    schema=["id", "raw_date"],
)
dates_df = dates_df.drop("id")

format = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dates_df.withColumn("date_formatted", to_date("raw_date", format)).show()

Above raises spark upgrade exception, as expected
org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: 
You may get a different result due to the upgrading to Spark >= 3.0: 
Fail to parse '2024-1-01' in the new parser. 
You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to 
LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, 
or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string.

And when I add config("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "CORRECTED") to the SparkSession, I get expected behaviour - no exceptions just nulls for records that don't match given format.
+----------+--------------+
|  raw_date|date_formatted|
+----------+--------------+
|2024-01-01|    2024-01-01|
| 2024-1-01|          null|
| 2024-01-1|          null|
|  2024-1-1|          null|
|  24-01-01|          null|
|   24-1-01|          null|
|   24-01-1|          null|
|    24-1-1|          null|
|2024/01/01|          null|
| 2024/1/01|          null|
| 2024/01/1|          null|
|  2024/1/1|          null|
|  24/01/01|          null|
|   24/1/01|          null|
|   24/01/1|          null|
|    24/1/1|          null|
|11/01/2024|          null|
| 11/1/2024|          null|
|  11/01/24|          null|
| 11/1/2024|          null|
+----------+--------------+

So for some reason this issue is only happening when running inside complicated/long jobs. What's also strange is that this upgrade exception is raised from different line in the code, depending on the env I run that job on. (exception is identical in both cases)

Local env, single node - fails at the very beginning of the job (stage 2/10)
Remote env, kubernetes cluster - fails at the end of the job when running df.rdd.getNumPartitions(). During final stage which saves DF into csv. (part of the code that fails locally passes without any problems)

Looks like it has to do something with available resources/partitions and complexity of the spark job. So my final guess was that something strange is happening with the job when logical plan grows too big so I tried checkpoints to truncate logical plan.
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as d:
    spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("/tmp/bb")
    df = df.checkpoint(True)

The problem is that it didn't change anything, still raising upgrade exception which hints to use either LEGACY or CORRECTED while spark session is already using CORRECTED mode instead of default EXCEPTION.
Unfortunately I can't share the code of the long job which reproduces this issue. But when it comes to date parsing, there is nothing fancy, just calls to to_date(col('foobar'), '<date_format>') and job is definitely running in CORRECTED mode. In LEGACY mode job passes but doesn't return desired outcome because date parsing is not as strict as in CORRECTED mode.

why not just implement yourself an udf to handle in code your several date formats instead of relying on a method which does not fully answer your needs ?

I want to avoid using UDFs because of performance impact they might have. Also, builtin  function in CORRECTED mode does fulfill my needs, at least in theory, but it looks like something breaks in this mode at some point of pyspark execution. Despite saying all of that I probably will have to use a UDF until I found out what makes CORRECTED mode behave so inconsistently in more complicated jobs.
